# Alpha transparency not uniform when plotting a shapefile with Geopandas

Tags: transparency, alpha, shapefile, geopandas, alpha-transparency

When plotting a shapefile with Geopandas, I need to make the features transparent.  When applying an alpha parameter, some of the features become less transparent than others.

> fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8.5,11))
>   ax =fig.add_axes([0.05,0.15,.9,.8])
>
> mapDF = gpd.read_file('hydrography.shp')
>
> mapDF.plot(color=('steelblue'), ax=ax, alpha=0.5)

I expected all the features to have uniform transparency, but some features are noticeably more transparent than others.  There is nothing different about those features.

[Please click here to see what I am describing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU8iT.png)

Does anyone know a way to fix this?  Thank you.

Comment: I suspect that some features are plotted on top of the others.

Comment: Thank you!  I checked in ArcMap, and you are absolutely right.

Comment: You can turn your comment into your own answer, and click to accept it. If your writing is nice, I will upvote the answer.

Answer (score 3):

As swatchai had suggested, my shapefile had multiple features stacked upon one another; thus the transparency was reduced.  I deleted the overlapping features, and the problem was solved.